# ListView Create cell programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I need to put a series of checkboxes in the cell of a ListView. The problem is that I do not know ahead of time how many. I am guessing, but please correct me if I am wrong, that I need to create it programmatically. There will only be a few cells so I am not worried about reusability. How do I approach doing that?

1. No xml just build the cell in the getView method --> is this as simple as creating a View and add to it?
2. xml but append checkboxes to the xml --> I have no idea how to do this.
3. Is there some sort of dynamic xml CheckBox list that I can use?

Comment: You want one row with multiple checkboxes or one checkbox per row?

Comment: I want one row with multiple checkboxes. I basically have two row styles one has checkboxes the other calls a picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer to use XML to separate the presentation of the controller (or code that controls the app)..

You just need to create a list view and define it's adapter. The adapter will have an XML (a row) where you can design the checkbox and the other elements that you want...

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) where you can see an example of a listview with an adapter.

-- edit:

In your case you need to add the checkboxes programmatically in your adapter. Just define a view in your xml where you can add your checkboxes.

-- edit2:
Here is an example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

   <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/checkboxContainer" >

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your adapter you

```
//get the container
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_YOUR_XML, parent, false);
RelativeLayout your_container = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxContainer);

//declare your checkbox
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(context);
cb.setText("your text");

// add the checkbox to your container
your_container.addView(cb);
```

This is just an example. I didn't test the code. Maybe you should use a linear layout instead of a relative layout to place your checkboxes easily..

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's exactly what I am struggling with. How do I "define a view in your xml where you can add your checkboxes".

Answer (score 0):

easiest and most flexible is to use the ArrayAdapter and make an XML layout that looks like the single cell you'd want. Put your data in the array, create the Adapter and assign it to the ListView, and boom, your list has the right number of rows (cells). You can also customize the binding easily so that each cell has some information based on the corresponding Array entry.

Comment: Sorry my question was ambiguous. I want one row with multiple checkboxes. I basically have two row styles one has checkboxes the other calls a picker.

Comment: Ah I did something like this once. Option 1 is good, just write code to create the checkboxes you want. But if you know there's a max # of checkboxes you'll use before you go to a picker, I'd create a cell with n checkboxes and then set the visibility of the last few to Visibility.GONE so that just the right number appears.

Comment: That would be a great solution but I don't have a max #. Might want to think about doing that though!!